# Pandas choose idxmin+1 (nth to last) values only

Tags: python, pandas

How can I choose only the nth to last index using idxmin in pandas?

```
df = data.loc[data.groupby("key1")["key2"].idxmin()]
```

only gives me the last value of course.

Having a dataframe of the form:

```
key1       key2
 a           1
 a           2
 a           3
 b           4
 b           5
 c           6
```

the desired result should be:

```
key1       key2
 a           2
 b           5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
df[df.groupby('key1')['key2'].transform(pd.DataFrame.rank) == 2]
```

OR

```
df[df.groupby('key1')['key2'].apply(lambda x: x.rank() == 2)]
```

Output:

```
  key1  key2
1    a     2
4    b     5
```

Comment: I keep getting the "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" error. Any idea why?

Comment: Hrm... No... You get it with these data? is key1 in the index?

Comment: No. It's with the real data. I'll dig in to see where the issue is. Probably your answer does solve the question as phrased, thank you!

Comment: I think I found the issue. I'm concatenating multiple data frames and did not set 'ignore_index=True'. Your solution does really solve the problem as stated. Thank you for the help!